# Do RemoteAction methods have access to page parameters?

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting

I'm getting a null exception for attempting to grab a record id from the url query params:  ApexPages.Currentpage().getParameters('id'). Can RemoteAction methods access these parameters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No,  not from apex.  But there's an easy workaround:

Pass them in from the script on the page using {!$currentpage.parameters.something}

You still need to check for nulls in the code because it might legitimately be null

Comment: Wow, I've been saving it to a hidden field on page load and then grabbing it later with JS. Didn't realize there was a VF global variable that handles it natively. Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't already, google salesforce global variables.  There are lots of handy things like user info, page info, session info, site info, etc.

Answer (score 10):

> Can RemoteAction methods access these parameters?

Nope :-)

By their very nature, RemoteAction methods are stateless. If you check out the HTTP request itself, it doesn't carry information about the invoking page or the request parameters on it.

If you need to operate on a specific record, you can reflect the Id in the remote method signature and then transmit it with the remote action invokation. For example:

**Extension.cls**

```
public class Extension {
  @RemoteAction static public void convert(Id recordId) {
    Object__c obj = [SELECT Status__c FROM Object__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
    obj.Status__c = 'converted';
    update obj;
  }
}
```

**Converter.page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Object__c" extensions="Extension">
  <apex:commandButton
    onclick="{!$RemoteAction.Extension.convert}('{!Id}', function() {});return false;"
    value="Convert"
  />
</apex:page>
```